# UIAlertView causing warning message on startup

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, compiler-warnings, nsnotifications

nilMy app needs to run a few checks then maybe display a `UIAlertView` any time my application becomes active. To do this I have registered for `didBecomeActiveNotification` and run my check here.

The issue occurs whenever my `UIAlertView` pops up during the ***initial launch***, it causes the "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" message. I'm guessing this is happening because `UIAlertView` is shown before `viewDidAppear:`.

How should I be triggering my `UIAlertView` if not in `didBecomeActiveNotification`?

```
2012-03-16 12:21:47.238 App[4181:707] viewDidLoad:
2012-03-16 12:21:47.462 App[4181:707] didBecomeActiveNotification:
2012-03-16 12:21:47.793 App[4181:707] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2012-03-16 12:21:48.500 App[4181:707] viewDidAppear:
```

Edit: To trigger this in a new project do the following.

1 New Project -> Single View Application

2 In Viewcontroller.m add the following to `viewDidLoad:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didBecomeActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

3 In ViewController.m add the following method

```
 -(void)didBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

4 Build and Run

Comment: How did you register for `didBecomeActiveNotification` ?

Comment: Inside `viewdidLoad` using `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didBecomeActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];`

Comment: I tried to show an alert at app-delegate at `applicationDidBecomeActive` *and* at root view controller's `didBecomeActiveNotification` registered with the code you provided - both works. Do you think there's something special with your app, maybe with root view controller initialization ?

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't work, it works fine. I just get that console warning and want to figure out why.

Comment: Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) i don't see such a warning. Can you confirm that the message is only visible with the alert shown and there's no such message without an alert ? Is it really a compiler warning or a console message by the way ?

Comment: Have updated my question with details on how to cause this notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as i said, no console messages, nor compiler-warning.
Can you confirm that the message is only visible with the alert shown and there's no such message without an alert ?

[image]

Comment: Yes it only occurs if the alert is shown. I see you are using simulator 5.1 and I am on 5.0 though so maybe it was some kind of bug which has been fixed in 5.1?

Comment: @trapper you are probably right, i'm able to reproduce the message agains 5.0 `Simulator`. But here's the good news: no message agains iOs 3.2 and 5.1 `devices`. I'll be able to test agains 5.0 device after the weekend only.

Comment: Tested in 5.1 simulator and I no longer have the error either.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I be triggering my UIAlertView if not in didBecomeActiveNotification?

I would trigger it in the root view controller.

Comment: The root view controller is not always on the top of view stack.

Comment: I am already doing everything above in the rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

Your `AppDelegate` can't launch `UIAlertViews`. That can only be done by a `ViewController`.

I have a similar thing in one of my apps, where I want to check something whenever the app launches or becomes active, and present a modal `viewController` to the user.

What I did was to create a new class, that has one method:

```
+(BOOL)checkIfShouldShowAlert
```

You can then call this method in each of your viewControllers' `viewWillAppear` methods, like so:

```
if ([myCheckerClass checkIfShouldShowAlert]) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle...
    [alertView show];
}
```

By using a separate class, it makes your code a lot simpler to update in the future!

Comment: I'm successfully creating alerts in the delegate `applicationDidBecomeActive`, you must be wrong. Also, if you read the question carefully, the alert is created in the view controller.

Comment: Oh! Well in that case --- the notification "became active" is probably already called by the time that the view becomes visible, so your viewController is only setting itself up as a recipient *after* the notification happened.

I use a single NSUserDefault BOOL in my app; I set it to YES before the app closes, and NO the first time any viewController calls myCheckerClass

Comment: Also: Are you using storyboarding or no? It sounds like you never create a RootViewController in your AppDelegate. Your AppDelegate should have an attribute called "window"; make sure that in applicationDidFinishLaunching you create a viewController and assign it to the AppDelegate's "window" attribute

Comment: Let me answer you. The problem exists for the app without `storyboard` where `UIWindow` is created and `UIViewController` view is added as window's subview at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. The flag of application being launched for the first time is useless as an alert might be shown at the application launch and we have that wired message then. Checking that application has been launched and showing an alert at `viewDidAppear` will be an overkill. Well, for me it will.